# Availability of nonlinear minimization function/library in math.net

Tags: c#, .net, math, statistics, math.net

Does anyone know if there any functions/libraries for  nonlinear minimization using Newton type method math.net or any other free .net library for that sake

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at MathNET Numerics on GitHub.

Comment: @Killercam, I tried to find there only but unfortunately I did not find the above functions, thought I am missing something, so asked here.